# DataFrame Manipulations using RCPP

Tags: c++, r, open-source, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to manipulate Big Data Frame (Almost in GB's). I have tried all possible solutions in R.

As We all know RCPP known for it's speed & efficiency.

I come across DataFrame::create() function to create DataFrame object.

*Are there any dedicated functions for DataFrame Read from R, Joins operations & Manipulations using RCPP packages?*

Thank you,
Harshal

DataFrame operation using RCPP R package

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. and to Rcpp!  The site here has a certain "standard" and mode; you are well advised to maybe [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  As for your question, I doubt it meets the standards here and should probably closed.  My recommendation to you would be to look into a few tutorials on `data.table`.  It was written for example what you have in mind, and you will most likely not be able to beat it with simple C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! We can not do DataFrame operations using RCPP?

Comment: If you have C++ experience, try the C++ DataFrame (https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame)